# Creating multiple class objects with a for loop in python

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having trouble with making multiple lines draw to the screen when using a class. I don't want to have to make several class instances of the same thing, just want to be able to append it to a list and have it fall. I've only managed to make one appear on the screen and that is all. Any help would be appreciated, thx.

```
import pygame
import random

#Classes
class Drop:
    def __init__(self, window, color, x, y,speed):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed = speed
        self.window = window
        self.color = color
        
    def fall(self):
        self.y = self.y + self.speed
        pygame.draw.line(self.window , self.color ,[ self.x , self.y],[self.x, self.y + 30], 2)
        
        


#functions

        
#Program Loop
def main():
    
    gameExit = True
    
#Making the raindrops
    for i in range(500):
        x = random.randint(10,500)
        y = 1
        uno = Drop(window , purple,x,y,speed)  
        rain.append(uno)
        

        
    while gameExit != False:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = False

        window.fill(white)
        
        uno.fall()
            
        pygame.display.update()
     

#Variables
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 500
DISPLAY_WIDTH = 800




rain = []

speed = 0.5

purple = (128,0,128)
white = (255,255,255)



#Game init

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Purple Rain")


main()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
uno.fall()
```

should be in the for-loop. Outside it will refer to the last drop -> You see only one

Right code:

```
window.fill(white) # screen-cleaning should be done first
for i in range(500):
    x = random.randint(10,500)
    y = 1
    uno = Drop(window , purple,x,y,speed)  
    rain.append(uno) 
    uno.fall() # changed
```

Comment: I changed it over and even the last drop never appeared.

Comment: Thanks they all appear.